# NICDSign issue: NICDSign client is not installed or running

Tags: software-installation, 22.04, signature

I am using Ubuntu 22.04. Recently I installed NICDSign and ProxKey Token Tool. Both of them are working.(Nicdsign.list and wdproxkey-token-tool.list etc are in var/lib/dpkg/info) 'NICDSign status: running...' and Token Tool identifies my name. Diagnostic Tool is working perfectly. But **NICDSign icon appeared on the Desktop doesn't show command in desktop properties**. I get a prompt: *'NICDSign client is not installed or running. If NICDSign client is already installed remove and reconnect the token before trying again'* only when I try to sign in using it. How to fix this problem?